# A question on the proof of Gelfand-Kazhdan theorem.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, gelfand-representation

Consider $F=\Bbb Q_p$ and $G=GL(n, F)$ and $\theta \in \operatorname{Aut(G)}$ s.t $\theta(g)=(g^t)^{-1}$

Now **Gelfand-Kazhdan theorem** says that:

For any representation $(\pi, V)$ of $G$, if we construct another representation $\pi^{\theta}(g)=\pi(\theta(g))$ then that will be equivalent to $\pi^{\vee}$, where $(\pi^{\vee}, V^{\vee})$ is the representation of $V^{\vee})$ i.e $\pi^{\vee}:G \to \operatorname{GL}(V^{\vee})$  such that $\pi^{\vee}(g)v^{\vee})(v)=v^{\vee}(\pi(g^{-1}v)$.

1. Now if I have any finite field $\Bbb F_p$ will it be possible to give me a particular intertwining operator on that because in general the proof goes using character theory in finite dimensional case.
2. Next I was wandering that if there would be any simple proof of Gelfand-Kazhdan theorem using basic linear algebra.

My question might seem to be odd, but I am in general trying to give generalisation of the theorem in the covering space of a group. So if I someone have some simple idea to prove it, please give that link or proof.

Comment: Remember, when you write a matrix for a linear transformation you are implicitly choosing a basis.  I'm pretty sure $(g^t)^{-1}$ is just this same action you described of G on $V^\vee$ when you expand it in the dual basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the earlier link you can also have a look

1) [A work of Alan Roche and Steven Spallone](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d17c/d1e0335b25d293f91c3ed0bfe03785340ca3.pdf)
2) [Work of K Balasubramanian](http://home.iiserb.ac.in/~bkumar/sdr%20paper%20Sp(4,F).pdf)
3) [Work of K Balasubramanian](https://home.iiserb.ac.in/~bkumar/sdr%20paper%20SL(n,F).pdf)
4) [A work of Alan Roche and Steven Spallone](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4746.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look at [this](http://home.iiserb.ac.in/~bkumar/sdr%20paper%20Sp(4,F).pdf). You will get a partial answer to your question.